# *.npy reader for windows

Tags: python, numpy

Does exist any *.npy files reader/visualizer ? (for Windows)

Comment: What's npy? Mind sharing a link?

Comment: I guess OP might have meant files saved by **numpy** - http://numpy.scipy.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a IDE for scientific python call [spyder](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/).  It has the ability to import all the data from a .npy file into the workspace.  All the variables in the workspace are shown in a nice user interface, so this may do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

My image viewer giv, see http://sourceforge.net/projects/giv/ , supports the display of 2D npy files.